# Wiki (or similar knowledge base platform) that allows inline annotation/comment threads

Tags: web-apps, collaboration, wiki, annotation

Conventional wiki software such as MediaWiki gives users one link to a "Talk" page per article. The comments therein can each refer to different sections of the article. This often results in a bit of a haphazard mess, in my experience.

I'm looking for a wiki that --ideally-- allows Reddit-style comment threads to be attached to any particle line of text in the article.

The comment trees could be located to the right side of the article and be minized (or truncated) by default, but expandable upon click or hover action.

Also, if the code be mostly client based (i.e., JavaScript) with minimal server side overhead, that would be a nice bonus.

A tall order perhaps, but does something like this exist?

Answer (score 4):

[Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/), as of a recent version, supports inline comment threads.

After selecting some text while viewing the page (not in edit mode), a button will pop up from the highlighted text with the option to add a comment. When someone else views the page, they will see the highlighted text, and clicking on it will display the thread at the right. After the question has been answered (and content changed if necessary), the author clicks a "resolve" link on the thread and the discussion is archived.

Comment: I've used inline comments in Confluence and they're by far the worst inline commenting I've ever seen. I would start listing the problems with them but it would take too long.

Comment: @Nemo Cool. What application is similarly powerful as Confluence and offers a better inline commenting experience?

Answer (score 2):

MediaWiki does allow inline comments, though the extensions to do so are quite experimental (like [Annotator](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?oldid=2736506) for MediaWiki 1.21).

Answer (score 1):

[Cryptpad](https://cryptpad.fr/) by XWiki calls itself the "zero-knowledge cloud". It is more a replacement for encrypted pads, etherpads and Google Docs than for a wiki, but you can use it with some wiki-like features if you have enough discipline (e.g. to cross-link related documents and archive the documents you need)

I'm using it with a few different groups and people quite often use the inline commenting feature of the [rich text editor](https://docs.cryptpad.fr/en/user_guide/apps/richtext.html). Nobody I know ever had problems with it.